# Checking exceptions in .NET solution (sources or binaries)

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I am search a way to disable usage (**throw new *exception* **) of specific exception in our c# solution.
If can I configure c# compiler and show compiled error if somebody try to throw a specific exception or, maybe, can I call a utility and analyze compiled binaries and show message if the specific exception was raises in our solution?

I am not look run-time solutions. I want to check in "development" time.

Igor.

Comment: Could you maybe tell us why you would want to do this?  If it's an outdated exception class you should use the Obsolete attribute, if it's another issue there may be something you're missing here.

Answer (score 3):

You may consider adding a custom rule(Warning/Error) to the FxCop and then build the solution after adding the FxCop project file into your solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the exception in question is your own exception, you can decorate the exception class with the [`Obsolete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx) attribute. Then the compiler will show a warning whenever the class is used.

```
[Obsolete("MyException is obsolete. Please use MyOtherException instead")]
public class MyException : Exception
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give [Gendarme](http://www.mono-project.com/Gendarme) a look; I'm not sure how trivial it is to write a new rule that can do what you want, but I'm hoping it would be easy enough. Failing that, check out [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/).